# DotNetOpenAuth Oauth 2, what to do with code response?

Tags: oauth-2.0, linkedin-api, dotnetopenauth

I am working on authorizing a LinkedIn app for users in our web application. In the base its using angularjs with a .NET web api backend on .NET 4.5.2.

I did get it to work until the callback. Here is the code:

```
public string GetAuthenticationUrl(string context, string redirectUrl)
{
        if(context == null)
            throw new ArgumentException(nameof(context));
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(redirectUrl))
            throw new ArgumentException(nameof(redirectUrl));

        var appContext = _applicationContextProvider.GetLinkedInApplicationContext();
        var linkedIn = new UserAgentClient(new AuthorizationServerDescription
        {
            TokenEndpoint = new Uri(appContext.AccessTokenEndpoint),
            AuthorizationEndpoint = new Uri(appContext.AuthorizationEndpoint),
            ProtocolVersion = ProtocolVersion.V20
        }, appContext.ClientId, appContext.ClientSecret);

        var target = linkedIn.RequestUserAuthorization(null, context, new Uri(redirectUrl));

        return target.AbsoluteUri;
    }
```

which returns a Url i can use to go to LinkedIn.
I authorize the application and get redirected successfully to my redirectUrl where i get a code and a state.

but what do i do next to request the access token?

```
public void Confirm(string state, string code)
{
// ?
}
```

I use dotnetopenauth 4.3

best reagrds
Jonas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i figured it out. So for future adventurers:

```
public void Confirm(string context, string code)
    {
        if (context == null)
            throw new ArgumentException(nameof(context));
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(code))
            throw new ArgumentException(nameof(code));

        var appContext = _applicationContextProvider.GetLinkedInApplicationContext();
        var linkedIn = new UserAgentClient(new AuthorizationServerDescription
        {
            TokenEndpoint = new Uri(appContext.AccessTokenEndpoint),
            AuthorizationEndpoint = new Uri(appContext.AuthorizationEndpoint),
            ProtocolVersion = ProtocolVersion.V20
        }, appContext.ClientId, appContext.ClientSecret)
        {
            ClientCredentialApplicator = ClientCredentialApplicator.PostParameter(appContext.ClientSecret)
        };

        var auth = linkedIn.ProcessUserAuthorization(new Uri($"http://fake.url?code={code}"), new AuthorizationState
        {
            Callback = new Uri("<addd original return_url here from code request>")
        });
    }
```